# QTableWidget. Emit cellChanged signal

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, emit

There is QTableWidget. I need to send cellChanged signal with row column and text. How can I do this?

--

I have already connected signal with slot. I need to **send** signal.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `connect` to catch `signal` `cellChanged(int,int)` when a cell is changed:

```
connect(yourTableWidget, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)), this, SLOT(doSomething(int, int)));
```

You have to create a `slot`, for example `doSomething`:

```
public slots:
void doSomething(int row, int column)
{
    // Get cell text
    QString text = yourTableWidget->item(row,column)->text();

    // Emit 
    emit somethingIsDone(row,column,text);
}
```

Create the signal `somethingIsDone` (or use an existing signal) which use (`int,int,QString`) parameters (*the parameters could be in another order*)

```
signals:
    void somethingIsDone(int row, int column, QString text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must make a slot function and use QObject::connect to connect its with `cellChanged` signal.

For example:

```
QTableWidget* widget;
widget = new QTableWidget(this);
connect(widget, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)), otherObject, SLOT(youSlot(int, int));
```

In your slot you can get QTableWidgetItem using received parameters: row and column number. And here you can emit your own signal containing also text.

```
QTableWidgetItem* item = widget->item(row, column);
QString textFromItem = item->data(Qt::UserRole);
emit cellChanged(row, column, textFromItem);
```

Of course, previously you have to declare your own signal:

```
signals:
   void cellChanged(int row, int col, QString text);
```

Your signal can be connected to other slot in the same way as `cellChanged(int, int)`